# How to catch array index out of bound in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I want to catch an error when access outside of array's bounds happens but it doesn't seem to throw an error.

```
let arr = [2,4,5];
let test = arr[3];
console.log(test);
```

I know that I can test for undefined and throw an error

```
if (arr[3] === undefined) throw new Error();
```

but how come I can't just do try and catch it like the following.

```
let arr = [2,4,5];
try {
      let tmp = arr[3];
    } catch(e) {
      lastIndex = findLastIndex(arr, high / 2, high);
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Accessing an undefined property in JavaScript does not cause a runtime error. It's just the way the language works.

Comment: Yes, JS doesn't throw an error when accessing a non-existing property. If you want to handle it, do it anticipatory: `if (i < arr.length) tmp = arr[i] else …`.

Comment: @Bergi that's a good solution

Answer (score 8):

As you can see, accessing a non-existent array index does not throw an error - the value "accessed" will simply be `undefined`. Ordinary objects work the same way:

```js
const obj = {};
// No error:
const val = obj.foo;

console.log(val);
```

But errors generally should not be used for control flow - errors should handle *exceptional* cases. For what you're doing, I'd use `if`/`else` instead, eg

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
if (4 in arr) {
  const val = arr[4];
  // ...
} else {
  console.log('4 is not in the arr');
}
```